# How I read specific data field from json response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ajaxq

I have json response coming in $.ajax function and I can alert as well the whole response, but How I can I alert specific field in response under "recordFound" function, for example First Name.

### JSON Response

```
{"StudentID":12,"StudentNumber_UWLID":21209510,"Title":"mr","FirstName":"Adam","MiddleName":null,"LastName":"Test"}
```

### Ajax function

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetStudentRecordByID", "StudentProfile")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { _GivenStudentUWLID: StudentUWLID },
            cache: false
        }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            if (data.RecordStatus == "NotAvailable")
            {
                $(this).MyMessageDialog({
                    _messageBlockID: "_StatusMessage",
                    _messageContent: "<div class='warningMessage'> <h4>Given Student Cannot Be Enter As Additional Tenant.</h4> <br/> Student Need to Have their Profile Completed On Student Village Portal Before Can Be Added As Additional Tenant Within The Tendency Form! <br/><br/> Or Enter Correct Student UWL ID "+"</div>",
                    _messageBlockWidth: "400px"
                });
            }
            else if(data.RecordStatus=="recordFound")
            {
                alert(data.Response);???????

                 $("#AdditionalTenent").find(".listedStudentTitle").val("dddadd");
            }

        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            alert("error");
            });

        });

    });
```

### ASP.NET-MVC Controller Sending JSON

```
 if (_entity != null)
            {
                var studentObj = new StudentLimitedInfo
                {
                    StudentNumber_UWLID = _entity.StudentNumber_UWLID,
                    StudentID = _entity.StudentID,
                    Title = _entity.Title,
                    FirstName = _entity.FirstName,
                    MiddleName = _entity.MiddleName,
                    LastName = _entity.LastName
                };

                var jsonObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(studentObj);

                return Json(new { Response = jsonObj, RecordStatus = "recordFound" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Comment: There is no `RecordStatus or Response` in the returned json data.

Comment: I have updated my question and I am serializing my data in json and I am sending via response object  and RecordStatus ="recordFound"

Comment: return Json(new { Response = jsonObj, RecordStatus = "recordFound" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: if I alert data.Response, I got all the records as I have stated in my question

Comment: `alert(data.Response.StudentID); // alert(12);` as per your response.

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer as following;

```
var paraed = JSON.parse(data.Response);

alert(paraed.Title + "   "+paraed.FirstName);
```

Comment: Remove `var jsonObj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(studentObj);`. Its just `return Json(new { Response = studentObj , ...` and then `alert(data.Response.Title + "   "+data.Response.FirstName);` Its pointless and unnecessary extra ovehead to serialize it with `JavaScriptSerializer` and then convert it back again.